# How to apply overloaded operator to this?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this-pointer

How to call an overloaded operator in another member function of a class in C++ ?

Comment: Show some code, please, in order to illustrate what you mean. Asked like this, your question is unlikely to get any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming it's overloaded as a member, you generally use `(*this)operator<parameter(s)>`, so if a class has an overload of `operator[]` that takes, say, an int parameter (e.g., `T &operator[](int index);`), another member function can invoke it with `(*this)[2]`.

If it's overloaded as a free function, you do pretty much the same sort of thing. For example, assuming you had a free function like:

```
my_string operator+(my_string const &a, my_string const &b);
```

You could invoke it from a member function like:

```
my_string operator+(my_string const &other) { 
   return (*this) + other;
}
```

Probably not useful in quite this simplistic of a case, but still shows the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguous but one of those three subanswers should work:

Whenever you want use `this` inside any (non-static) member function you can do it:

```
class A {
    int b;

    void foo() {
        this->b;
    }

    void bar() {
        foo(); // Those calls are the same
        this->foo();

        this->b;
    }
}
```

C++ takes care about `this` being the same object.

---

When you want to call overloaded operator like `operator+=`, you may do:

```
void foo()
{
    *this += bar;
    (*this)[bar]; // for operator[]
}
```

---

And if you need to call operator of parent class:

```
class A, public Base {

    void foo() 
    {
        this->Base::operator+= bar; // Equivalent syntax again
        ((Base)*this) += bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The overloaded operator will be called automatically and there is no need for explicit calling. Here is a quick example of operator overloading:

```
class MyNumber
{
private:
    int number_;

public:
    MyNumber() : number_(0) { }

    MyNumber& operator++() // prefix
    {
        ++number_;
        return *this;
    }

    MyNumber operator++(int) // postfix
    {
        MyNumber result = *this;
        ++number_; // Calls this->operator++(void);
        return result;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    MyNumber number;
    number++;
    ++number;
    return 0;
}
```